# Non-destructively deleting first element of array?

Tags: java, c++, arrays

What I am trying to do is convert this C++ function to Java:

```
void print(int x[], int l)
{
     if (l != 0) {
         cout << x[0] << ",";
     print(x+1,l-1);
     }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do, but it won't work:

```
void print(int x[])
{
     if (x.length != 0) {
         cout << x[0] << ",";
         print(x + 1); //<--- ERROR!
     }
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do it recursively? Or do you...?

Comment: Just am trying to learn Java? Wanted to see if I could do the same thing as in C++ by asking this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java does not have pointers in the same way as C++. That is, you can't "move" the array pointer `x` further along the array. What I would suggest is passing a *starting index* to your function something like this:

```
void print(int x[], int start)
{
    if (start < x.length) {
        if (start > 0) {
            System.out.println(x[start] + ",");
        }
        print(x, start + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays have a `length` property, so you don't even need to go through any of this nonsense:

```
void print(int[] x)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
         System.out.print(x[i] + ",");
}
```

Comment: That's not a direct translation of the code though. Note that in C & C++, you could just use a for-loop too. And especially in C++, you'd likely use a `std::vector` rather than a raw array.

Comment: Actually, in C++/C you can't determine the length of an array programmatically, hence the need for clumsy workarounds like in the original post. It's so much easier iteratively when you have a length property.

Comment: The `l` parameter in the C/C++ code *is* the length, so you could just do `for(int i=0; i < l; ++i) cout << x[i] << ", ";`.

Comment: I know that. I'm just trying to show that recursion isn't necessary at all in either case. Nobody but me is bothering to ask the *right* questions, just helping out with a literal translation that might not even be needed. I'm posting what I think is the best answer to what I see is the real question and I won't budge until I know why the original poster wants it done this way. I'm not going to encourage pointless hacks when they aren't needed.

Comment: Note that the poster even tried to use `cout` in the Java code. Decent chance s/he is a beginner to the language, in which case the right answer is the one that encourages good habits and approaches, not bad ones.

Comment: It's no "hack" in any sense. The code itself may be highly pointless to us (why increment `x`? why only use `l` as the continue condition?), but maybe the OP is learning some recursion (who knows why he's porting that to Java then). Note that I'm not disagreeing with you, the comment was just meant as more of a note than anything else. :)

Comment: :) Thanks for thinking about me.